# El operador '==' no se puede aplicar a 'default' y un operando de tipo 'T'

Tags: c#, operador, genericos

Estoy escribiendo una estructura envolvente para representar un dato manipulable, en un proyecto a modo de aprendizaje.

La misma, puede contener cualquier cosa, ya sea `int`, `System.DateTime` e incluso `object` o `System.Array`.

Ya he definido varios métodos, propiedades y eventos de utilidad en la misma para alterar el dato que contiene o detectar cambios en el mismo, pero entiendo que la parte relevante para la pregunta es la siguiente:

```
public struct Data<T>
{
    private T m_value;
    
    public Data(T value)
    {
        m_value = value;
    }
    
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get => m_value == default;
    }
}
```

Donde necesito saber si el dato de mi estructura fue definido o no (está vacío o no) y, para lograr esto, implementé la propiedad booleana `IsEmpty`, la cual devuelve el resultado de la comparación entre `m_value` y [`default`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default).

Dado que mi dato puede ser tanto un tipo de referencia (`class`) anulable o un tipo de valor (`struct`) no anulable, no puedo ampararme en `null`. Por ello uso `default`.

Mi problema, es que `m_value == default` produce un error, que me dice que el operador de igualdad `==` no se puede aplicar a `T` y `default`  porque `T` es un tipo de parámetro del que no se conoce que sea un tipo de referencia.

Entonces, ¿De qué forma puedo comparar mi dato con su valor por defecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las estructuras mutables son una mala idea, como dijo `InBetween` en [esta entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44843551/9443618) de SO.

> Las estructuras mutables son fuente de todo tipo de dolores de cabeza, comportamientos inesperados y errores sutiles que pueden volverte loco.

Si deseas crear un tipo de dato mutable (manipulable) deberías optar por un tipo de referencia (`class`) en su lugar.

---

Ahora bien, tu problema se debe a que `T` es un [tipo genérico](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics), que dicho de forma simplificada, es un tipo del que el compilador no sabe si será un tipo de referencia (clase) o un tipo de valor (estructura). Básicamente puede ser cualquier cosa.

Para entender mejor esto, propondré dos casos de ejemplo:

**A) Operador de igualdad aplicado a tipos de referencia**

Cuando aplicas el operador de igualdad `==` a dos tipos de referencia, tal que:

```
public class MyClass
{}

MyClass mc1 = new MyClass();
MyClass mc2 = new MyClass();

Console.WriteLine(mc1 == mc2);
Console.WriteLine(mc2 == mc1);
Console.WriteLine(mc1 == mc1);
Console.WriteLine(mc2 == mc2);
```

Obtendrás los siguientes resultados:

```
Console.WriteLine(mc1 == mc2); // Esto es Falso
Console.WriteLine(mc2 == mc1); // Esto es Falso
Console.WriteLine(mc1 == mc1); // Esto es Verdadero
Console.WriteLine(mc2 == mc2); // Esto es Verdadero
```

Esto se debe a que, en este caso, el compilador entiende que se trata de tipos de referencia, los cuales de por sí admiten el operador de igualdad `==` que compara su referencia, es decir, compara la dirección en memoria que apunta a cada objeto. Cuando creas un nuevo objeto (`new MyClass()`), a su vez, creas una nueva referencia, por lo cual, las referencias que se almacenan en `mc1` y `mc2` son diferentes entre sí, pues cada una es un objeto distinto (aunque tengan el mismo nombre de tipo).

**B) Operador de igualdad aplicado a tipos de valor**

Cuando aplicas el operador de igualdad `==` a dos tipos de valor, tal que:

```
public struct MyStruct
{}

MyStruct ms1 = new MyStruct();
MyStruct ms2 = new MyStruct();

Console.WriteLine(ms1 == ms2);
Console.WriteLine(ms2 == ms1);
Console.WriteLine(ms1 == ms1);
Console.WriteLine(ms2 == ms2);
```

Obtendrás los siguientes resultados:

```
Console.WriteLine(ms1 == ms2); // Error: El operador == no se puede aplicar a MyStruct
Console.WriteLine(ms2 == ms1); // Error: El operador == no se puede aplicar a MyStruct
Console.WriteLine(ms1 == ms1); // Error: El operador == no se puede aplicar a MyStruct
Console.WriteLine(ms2 == ms2); // Error: El operador == no se puede aplicar a MyStruct
```

Esto se debe a que los tipos de valor no pueden compararse por referencia, que es lo que el compilador entiende que intentas hacer cuando aplicas el operador `==`, comparar dos tipos de valor por referencia, lo cual, claramente es imposible. Las estructuras no presentan una definición para el operador de igualdad.

---

Entendido lo anterior, ya conoces la causa de tu problema: intentas aplicar un operador de igualdad `==` a un tipo que posiblemente no lo admita.

Existen algunas alternativas a `==` para estos casos:

-- [`System.Object.Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-7.0)

```
public bool IsEmpty
{
    get
    {
        if (m_value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return m_value.Equals(default(T));
    }
}
```

(Acá se puede comparar el tipo genérico con `null`, más no con `default` porque un genérico puede ser un tipo de referencia anulable, pero si no (si es un tipo de valor), se desconoce la forma de compararlo).

-- [`System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0)

```
public bool IsEmpty
{
    get => System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(m_value, default);
}
```

(Acá la validación de valores `null` la hace el `EqualityComparer<>`. Esta es mi opción predilecta para estos casos).

-- [`where (restricción de tipo genérico)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)

```
public struct Data<T> where T : class
{
    ...
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get => m_value == null;
    }
}
```

(Es una opción, puedes limitar (cuando aplique) tu tipo genérico para que solo admita tipos de referencia, y con esto, puedes usar el operador de igualdad `==` porque el compilador ya sabe el tipo que va a tratar y sabe que puede ser comparado por referencia).

**Edito:** Gracias a @Mateo por sugerir el uso de `Nullable<T>`. Esto es [Tipos de valor que admiten valores NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) y no se debe confundir con [Tipos de referencia que aceptan valores NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references).

-- `Nullable<T>`

```
public struct Data<T?>
{
    T? m_value;
    ...
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get => ! m_value.HasValue; // O m_value == null
    }
}
```

(Acá, el tipo de `T` es `Nullable<T>`, lo que significa que siempre acepta valores `NULL` y, en caso de presentar este valor (o la propiedad booleana `HasValue` de `Nullable<T>` en `false`) significa que `m_value` está vacía)

---

Adjunto además [esta entrada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004873/why-cant-the-operator-be-applied-to-a-struct-and-defaultstruct) de SO que presenta algunas soluciones adicionales para este caso.

Comment: En lugar de `where` también puedes usar un nullable.

Comment: Agradezco tu sugerencia @Mateo, lo he agregado a mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien está es una pregunta autorespondida y entiendo que se enfoca en el problema de la igualdad `m_value == default`. A mi parecer hay un problema en la lógica planteada que es anterior al problema de la igualdad, lo que me recuerda al [problema xy](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3360/qu%C3%A9-es-el-problema-xy).

El problema original es:

> "necesito saber si el dato de mi estructura fue definido o no"

Si yo defino `int a = 0`, siendo cero el valor `default` de un int, el condicional `m_value == default` ya no resulta, porque yo he definido la variable pero casualmente la definí con el mismo valor que su `default`

Entonces yo lo veo como problema de requerimientos (por llamarlo de alguna manera). El cual es que `IsEmpty` retorne true si no ha sido setado y false en caso contrario.

Esto es fácilmente manejable si creo una propiedad Value y cada vez que defino un valor pongo a `IsEmpty` en false

```
public struct Data<T>
{
    public Data(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    private T m_value;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return m_value;
        }
        set
        {
            IsEmpty = false;
            m_value = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; } = true;
}
```

Luego podemos escarbar más hondo en el problema, y pensar **¿Tiene sentido una estructura envolvente que no envuelve nada?**

Quizás lo tenga (no entiendo bien el contexto del problema), pero supongamos que no tenga ningún sentido, entonces viene la segunda pregunta: **¿Por qué necesito saber si el valor fue definido?**

Respuesta: Por una característica de las estructuras en c#, las cuales deben tener un constructor sin parámetros y público, y de no tenerlo se crea por default. Lo cual me permite instanciar de esta manera: `Data<int> data1 = new Data<int>();` es decir sin agregar valor a envolver (a causa del constructor default) y lo que provoca la cadena de problemas que dan origen a la pregunta:

- Saber si la variable ha sido definida o no
- Y luego al problema de la igualdad `m_value == default`

Entonces si yo transformo la estructura a una clase o a un registro, ya no tendría el problema. Ya que ahora no puedo crear una clase Data sin asignar un valor para que envuelva, que en mi opinión sería lo lógico

```
public class Data<T>  // public record Data<T>
{
    public Data(T value)
    {
        //etc
```

Comment: +1: Gracias por tu aporte Yussef, es un excelente complemento a esta publicación. A veces, he tenido algunos inconvenientes en C# para comparar genéricos con el valor por defecto que presentan cuando no están asignados, por ello quise compartir esta info en SOes centrandome en la comparación por si a alguien le resulta útil. Además usé una estructura en la pregunta a propósito para sugerir el cambio a una clase en la respuesta.